# Where is Deus Ex: Human Revolution's "Missing Link" DLC on Xbox One?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I just installed the Xbox 360 backwards compatible DE:HR game on my Xbox One after today's update which contained the game.

It installed fine and I could also installed my "Explosive Mission Pack" DLC. Since it didn't offer to install "Missing Link" I went to check my Microsoft account but it showed up as purchased, so I remembered right having purchased it previously.

Where or how can I install download the Missing Link for Xbox One?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Major Nelson's January Games with Gold post](http://majornelson.com/2015/12/21/xbox-live-games-with-gold-for-january-2016/), The Missing Link DLC isn't playable on Xbox One yet:

> NOTE: Deus Ex: Human Revolution is available to download, free to all
>   Gold members, starting January 16th and is playable on Xbox One.
>   However, Deus Ex’s DLC “The Missing Link” can only be played on Xbox
>   360. We are working hard to make this content available on Xbox One in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

According to [a post in the TrueAchievements forum](http://www.trueachievements.com/forum/viewthread.aspx?tid=772332&anchor=6080255#m6080255) from Feb 14th 2016 the DLC is now available for Xbox One which I have just verified by downloading it myself.